# extract string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
fix_release='Ubuntu 16.04 LTS'

p = re.compile(r'(Ubuntu)\b(\d+[.]\d+)\b')
fix_release = p.search(fix_release)
logger.info(fix_release) #fix_release is None
```

I want to extract the string 'Ubuntu 16.04'

But, result is None.... How can I extract the correct sentence?

Comment: First of all, correct your test string. You have written `Ubutu` instead of `Ubuntu`. Secondly, you can try this regex: [`Ubuntu\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/iGzyET/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused the word boundary `\b` with white space, the former matches the boundary between a word character and a non word character and consumes zero character, you can simply use `r'Ubuntu \d+\.\d+'` for your case:

```
fix_release='Ubuntu 16.04 LTS'
p = re.compile(r'Ubuntu \d+\.\d+')
p.search(fix_release).group(0)
# 'Ubuntu 16.04'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

`Ubuntu\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGzyET/1)

**Explanation:**

- `Ubuntu` - matches `Ubuntu` literally
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a white-space, as many as possible
- `\d+` - matches 1+ digits, as many as possible
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - matches a `.` followed by 1+ digits, as many as possible. A `?` at the end makes this part optional.

Note: In your regex, you are using `\b` for the spaces. `\b` returns 0 length matches between a word-character and a non-word character. You can use `\s` instead